# Run each loop at a different time interval

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm currently working on a program that pits two simulated fighters against one another. The way I have it right now, each round is done and the output is printed all at once (virtually all at once because it is calculated so fast).

How would I take the below code and make it so that actions in the second loop occur in pseudo real time where it executes x amount of seconds where x is a random roll? Any suggestions or guidance would be great. I would even settle for the second while loop executing every three seconds or so. This is a prototype for now and the simulation will get more varied so reading the output may get more interesting.

```
public static void fight(Character player1, Character player2, int roundMax){
        player1.setTempHitPoints(player1.getHitPoints());
        player2.setTempHitPoints(player2.getHitPoints());
        int r = ROUND;
        while(!isFightOver(player1, player2)){
            roundTimer = 0;
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Round " + r + " FIGHT!");
            System.out.println("================");
            while(roundTimer < roundMax && !isFightOver(player1, player2)){
                roundTimer = roundTimer + Commands.roll(10);
                round(player1, player2);
                timerPrint(roundTimer, roundMax);
            }
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Round " + r + " OVER!");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("");

            if(!isFightOver(player1, player2)){
                Commands.rest(player1);
                Commands.rest(player2);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            r++;
        }
            declareWinner(player1, player2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Thread.sleep()` to slow down the processing.
E.g. `Thread.sleep(1000)` causes the current thread to suspend execution for a second (1000 ms). Can you use that method judiciously to put delays into the code? You can use [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate random numbers.

```
Random random = new Random();

Thread.sleep((random.nextInt(6) + 1) * 1000);  // Delays from 1 - 6 secs
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense for the prototype that this is. I may have to find a more elegant situation later that is a little more consistent in the future, but this is a good start. Thank you!